# Escape characters (0x1b/27) in binary packages don't get sent through Wi-Fi and corrupt message during transmission

Tags: c, embedded, protocol-buffers, nanopb

I am developing on an embedded system (STM32F4) and I tried to send some data to a simple Windows Forms client program on the PC side. When I used a character based string format everything was working fine but when I changed to a binary package to increase performance I run into an problem with Escape characters.

I'm using nanopb to implement Googles Protocol Buffer for transmission and I observed that in 5% of package I'm receiving exceptions in my client program telling me that my packages are corrupted.

I debugged in WireShark and saw that in this corrupted package the size was 2-4 bytes smaller than the original package size. Upon further inspecting I found out that the corrupted packages always included the binary value 27 and other packages never included this value. I searched for it and saw that this value represents an escape character and that this might lead to problems.

The technical document of the Wi-Fi module I'm using (Gainspan GSM2100) mentions that commands are preceded by an escape character so I think I need to get rid of this values in my package.

I couldn't find a solution to my problem so I would appreciate if somebody more experienced could led me to the right approach to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you sending the data? Are you using a library or sending raw bytes? According to [the manual](https://s3.amazonaws.com/site_support/uploads/document_upload/Serial_to_WiFi_Command_Reference_5_13.pdf), your data commands should start with an escape sequence, but also have **data length** specified:

```
// Each escape sequence starts with the ASCII character 27 (0x1B),
// the equivalent to the ESC key. The contents of < > are a byte or byte stream.
// - Cid is connection id (udp, tcp, etc)
// - Data Length is 4 ASCII char represents decimal value
//   i.e. 1400 bytes would be '1' '4' '0' '0' (0x31 0x34 0x30 0x30).
// - Data size must match with specified length. 
//   Ignore all command or esc sequence in between data pay load.
<Esc>Z<Cid><Data Length xxxx 4 ascii char><data>
```

Note the remark regarding data size: *"Ignore all command or esc sequence in between data pay load"*.

For example, this is how the [GSCore::writeData function in GSCore.cpp](https://github.com/Pinoccio/library-gainspan-s2w/blob/master/src/GSModule/GSCore.cpp#L336) looks like:

```
// Including a trailing 0 that snprintf insists to write
uint8_t header[8]; 

// Prepare header: <esc> Z <cid> <ascii length>
snprintf((char*)header, sizeof(header), "\x1bZ%x%04d", cid, len);

// First, write the escape sequence up to the cid. After this, the
// module responds with <ESC>O or <ESC>F.
writeRaw(header, 3);

if (!readDataResponse()) {
    if (GS_LOG_ERRORS && this->error)
        this->error->println("Sending bulk data frame failed");
    return false;
}

// Then, write the rest of the escape sequence (-1 to not write the
// trailing 0)
writeRaw(header + 3, sizeof(header) - 1 - 3);+

// And write the actual data
writeRaw(buf, len);
```

This should most likely work. Alternatively, a dirty hack *might* be to "escape the escape character" before sending, i.e. replace each 0x27 with two characters (0x27 0x27) before sending - but this is just a wild guess and I am presuming you should just check the manual.

Comment: I'm packing the data using the library nanopb. Thank you, I will try your idea and then report if it worked!

Comment: Thank you! Your suggestion about data size led me to the root of the problem. I used the message type: <Esc>
UCID
remote address:
remote port:
before but I changed to <Esc>Y<CID>
remote address:
remote port:<Data
Len 4 digit
ascii><Data>. 
Including the data size prevented the module from executing that escape characters!